# How do I get the script path in Dart?

Tags: dart

I need to find out the directory in which the Dart script (which is currently running) is located. How do I go about doing this?

Previously, this was possible through `new Options().script`, but that class is no more. The arguments list from `main(args)` doesn't help, since it only contains arguments, not the executed Dart file (at least on Mac OS X).

Comment: This functionality was moved to the new Platform class in `dart:io`, and it's now a static getter. So, the correct way to find out the path to the currently executing Dart script is:

    `var path = Platform.script;`

If found out literally 5 seconds after posting this question.

Comment: This was because, Dart SDK is still unstable. I think when the major version will be released, then these problems will be less.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [BREAKING CHANGE: dart:io Platform and Options are deprecated, and will be removed](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/announce/AuTix5oPNjI) and [Breaking Change: Platform.script is a Uri, dart:platform library is gone](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/announce/Ny0kV2qBg6A) `new Options().script` should be replaced by `Platform.script`.

Note that `Platform.script` returns an [Uri](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/Uri-class.html) and you should consider using [toFilePath](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Uri/toFilePath.html) to get the file path from the file URI.

Comment: This answer reads as a little confusing.

Answer (score 3):

As noted the simple method is:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

print(Platform().script);
> file:///home/..../dcli_unit_tester/bin/dcli_unit_tester.dart
```

This is a file url, so to get the actual path use:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

print(Platform().script.toFilePath());
```

Of course you wanted the directory rather than the script so:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

final pathToScript = Platform().script.toFilePath();
final pathToDirectory = dirname(pathToScript);
print(pathToDirectory);
> /home/..../dcli_unit_tester/bin
```

There are a few things you should understand when attempting to get the directory of the script in that the directory will change depending on how you run the script.

In particular if running your script from a globally activated package then you might not (should not) want to use the script's dirirectory for storing things.

## execute .dart from cli

Here is the output from Platform if you run it from the cli:

```sh
dart bin/dcli_unit_tester.dart  -p
executable:  dart
script: file:///home/..../dcli_unit_tester/bin/dcli_unit_tester.dart
```

## execute script when globally activated

Now if you run the same script from a globally activated package:

```sh
pub global activate dcli_unit_tester
dcli_unit_tester -p
executable: dart
script: file:///home/..../.pub-cache/global_packages/dcli_unit_tester/bin/dcli_unit_tester.dart-2.14.2.snapshot
```

In this case the directory is in pub-cache which by nature is transitory, so don't store anything that you want to get back later.

## execute from compiled script

Now if you compile the script:

```sh
dart compile exe bin/dcli_unit_tester.dart
bin/dcli_unit_tester.exe -p

executable:  bin/dcli_unit_tester.exe
script: file:///home/..../dcli_unit_tester/bin/dcli_unit_tester.exe
```

## execute from within a unit test

If you run the same test from a unit test the script will be the test.dll file not you script.
I will update this answer once I work out how to get the script directory when running under unit tests (if it is even possible).

## using dcli

If you are building a console app you can use the dcli package:

```dart
import 'package:dcli/dcli.dart'
print(DartScript.self.pathToScript);
print(DartScript.self.pathToScriptDirectory);
> /home/..../dcli_unit_tester/bin/dcli_unit_tester.dart
> /home/..../dcli_unit_tester/bin
```