# Get path to directory from which script has been started

Tags: dart, dart-io

For example, I have this structure:

```
/home/user <- my current dir
/home/user/app/bin/main.dart <- entry point of my application
```

How I can get a path to the folder from which the script has been started? For example, I start `main.dart` from `/home/user` folder by:

```
dart app/bin/main.dart
```

Inside `main.dart` I need get the path `/home/user`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume this is what you are looking for.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print(Platform.script);
  print(Platform.script.toFilePath(windows: true));

  // or

  print(Directory.current.absolute.path);
}
```

see also [How do I get the script path in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906391)

Comment: There is also `Uri.base`